# How to create a weekly repetition with a datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

I would like to create an event repetition with a datepicker and a `<v-text-field>` where users can choose on how many week repeats the event example:

I select monday october 18th and i want to repeat the event twice so i have to do 18 + 7 = 25th october and then 25 + 7 = october 32th so 1 november

I do not know how to do the math in my script:

```html
<v-col cols="12" sm="6">
  <VueCtkDateTimePicker
    v-model="create_event.start"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
    formatted="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
    label="Date et heure de début"
    minuteInterval="10"
  />
  <br />
  <VueCtkDateTimePicker
    v-model="create_event.end"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
    formatted="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
    label="Date et heure de fin"
    minuteInterval="10"
  />
</v-col>
<v-col cols="12">
  <v-text-field
    label="Nombre de répétition"
    v-model="create_event.nb"
  ></v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

Comment: Is this the date-time picker you use? https://github.com/chronotruck/vue-ctk-date-time-picker

Comment: @vahdet yes this the date-time picker i use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my script :

```
async validate(){
  var url = "https://sportmanagementsystemapi.herokuapp.com/api/event/" + localStorage.id;
  var bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.set("titre", this.create_event.name);
  bodyFormData.set("nom_coach", this.create_event.nom_coach);
  bodyFormData.set("details", this.create_event.details);
  bodyFormData.set("date_debut", this.create_event.start);
  bodyFormData.set("date_fin", this.create_event.end);
  bodyFormData.set("role", this.create_event.role);
  bodyFormData.set("facture_client", this.create_event.facture_client);
  bodyFormData.set("facture_coach", this.create_event.facture_coach);
  await axios.post(url, bodyFormData, {
    headers: {
      token: localStorage.token
    }
  });
  var i;
  if(this.create_event.nb != 0) {
    for(i = 0; i < this.create_event.nb; i++) {
      var oldTime = this.create_event.start.split(' ')[1]; 
      var start = new Date(this.create_event.start); 
      var [date, month, year] = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate()+7).toLocaleDateString().split('/'); 
      this.create_event.start = year + '-' + month + '-' + date + ' ' + oldTime;
      var oldTimeend = this.create_event.end.split(' ')[1]; 
      var end = new Date(this.create_event.end); 
      var [date, month, year] = new Date(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDate()+7).toLocaleDateString().split('/'); 
      this.create_event.end = year + '-' + month + '-' + date + ' ' + oldTimeend;
      bodyFormData.set("titre", this.create_event.name);
      bodyFormData.set("nom_coach", this.create_event.nom_coach);
      bodyFormData.set("details", this.create_event.details);
      bodyFormData.set("date_debut", this.create_event.start);
      bodyFormData.set("date_fin", this.create_event.end);
      bodyFormData.set("role", this.create_event.role);
      bodyFormData.set("facture_client", this.create_event.facture_client);
      bodyFormData.set("facture_coach", this.create_event.facture_coach);
      await axios.post(url, bodyFormData, {
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.token
        }
      });
    }
  }
  this.dialog = false;
  window.location.reload();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the date using browser date function

lets say, textfield input repetition = 7

```
new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() + 7)
```

It returns 7 days after from the current date

Below is the example for above code:

```js
var startDate = new Date(2019, 9, 25); // 10/25/2019 (MM/DD/YYYY)
var repetetion = 7;

var endDate  = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate() + repetetion);

console.log(endDate);
```

Comment: can you give me an example in relation to my variables ?

Comment: no i want to create an event with a start date and an end date then i want to copy the event with a start date +7 and a end date +7 its's for a planning if someone had same event every week

Comment: I've shared the approach and you have to make changes to your code using this approach to update start date + 7 and endDate +7 on copy

Comment: how to add time with ?

Comment: Like this you can set new Date(2019, 9, 25, 10, 09, 36) // (year, month(index- 9 means october, date, hour, mins, secs), just run this in console, you will see the values you expected new Date(2019, 9, 25 + 7, 10, 09, 36).

Comment: Instead of hardcoded values, you can pass the values from the vue data properties

Comment: i want to do that this.create_event.start = new Date(this.create_event.start.getFullYear(), this.create_event.start.getMonth(), this.create_event.start.getDate()+7); but this.create_event.start is a string not a date

Comment: can you share the exact string you have in this.create_event.start??

Comment: I get this with the console.log(this.create_event.start) = "2019-11-15 11:00"

Comment: Use like this 
var start = new Date(this.create_event.start);

this.create_event.start = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate()+7);

Comment: Tue Nov 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) it's work but I would like to have the same format and the time is not taken

Comment: Use like this Use like this 

var oldTime = this.create_event.start.split(' ')[1];

var start = new Date(this.create_event.start);

this.create_event.start = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate()+7).toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, '-') + ' ' + oldTime;

Comment: i just have one more problem i get this "12-11-2019 11:50" an i want this "2019-11-12 11:50"

Comment: Use like this 

var oldTime = this.create_event.start.split(' ')[1];

var start = new Date(this.create_event.start);

var [date, month, year] = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), start.getDate()+7).toLocaleDateString().split('/'); 


this.create_event.start = year + '-' + month + '-' + date + ' ' + oldTime;